# python: how do I use datetime to change the format of date

Tags: python, datetime

I have date in string format, which looks like this

`extractDate = '5/21/20'` 
it is currently in mm/dd/yy format

I am trying to convert it to yyyymmdd format, so I should get 20200521

below is what I tried and it gives me error

```
from datetime import datetime
extractDate2 = datetime.strptime(extractDate, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

I am getting this error

```
ValueError: time data '5/21/20' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Where am I going wrong?

thanks,

Comment: I suggest checking the [documentation for strptime() and strftime() behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to check the syntax of your format strings.

Comment: a good overview of format codes can also be found at https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a lowercase "y" if you're giving 2-digit years to `strptime()`

(protip:  look into the "dateutil" library.  It will save you many headaches.)